# play audio file in the background using a service

Tags: java, android, audio

I tried playing the sound in the background service, but when I press the "play" button, the sound plays for a moment, and then the application terminates directly, this is my code :

```
public class AudioService extends Service {
        private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            // Start the foreground service
            startForegroundService();

            // Create the media player and set the audio file to play
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song_1);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

            // Start playing the audio
            mediaPlayer.start();

            return START_STICKY;
        }

        private void startForegroundService() {
            // Create the notification for the foreground service
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow)
                    .setContentTitle("Background Audio Service")
                    .setContentText("Playing audio in the background");

            // Start the foreground service with the notification
            startForeground(1, builder.build());
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // Return null because this service is not bound to any activity
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // Release the media player and stop the foreground service
            mediaPlayer.release();
            stopForeground(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you starting the service, and are you calling `stopService()` at all?

Comment: buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(view -> {
          
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AudioService.class);
            startService(serviceIntent);
        });

        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(view -> {
          
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AudioService.class);
            stopService(serviceIntent);
        });

Comment: "then the application terminates directly" -- are you crashing? If so, examine Logcat to see the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.release()' on a null object reference
        at com.audio.example.AudioService.onDestroy(AudioService.java:47)

Comment: Something is destroying your service before `onStartCommand()` is being called. Are you calling `stopService()` anywhere else?

Comment: Of course not, I don't know why, the code is completely written